# Intellij - adding module to imported git project

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a git project which I check out using IntelliJ with 
VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git
This project was not created in IntelliJ and so has no .iml files etc.
I choose "Create from existing sources".
I also leave checked the two directories that IntelliJ has correctly identified as containing source files, the root directory (Ruby) and public (Static Web).
No Frameworks Detected. Open in new window.

So far so good. Here is the problem

Now once the project opens it contains only the root directory in the Project Browser. The src subdirectory (public) is not present.

[image: Not present]

When I add the public directory as a new module or import as an existing module the directory appears but all of it's files are coloured brown. IntelliJ does not recognise this subdirectory or it's content as being under version control.

[image: Not recognized]

How on earth can I check out this project and have IntelliJ provide this subdirectory in the project browser and recognise these files as being under version control?

I am using IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Import from existing sources option works only for Java projects right now, [here is the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91446).

You can add new module and specify the existing folder as its root instead of importing. If you need several modules, create a new empty project first, then add modules, but don't use import.

Comment: Thanks yes. Infact if I repeat the process and deselect the checkbox for the root level directory in the "create from existing sources" step the project loads perfectly.